# Layering Solution Customisations

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I've read that you can use solutions to create layers of customisations. I'm not 100% sure what this means.

Does it mean that I can layer customisations in a similar fashion I can layer graphics using photoshop? Then if I find that 1 layer is wrong, I can simply delete it, revealing the layers underneath it?

If that's how solution layers work in CRM, that is absolutely amazing, if that is not how they work. How do I delete a bad layer, to revert back to a previous state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CRM solutions are rather complicated and not as simple as you'd think, and there tend to be lots of gotchas.  There are two different types of solutions, managed and unmanaged.  Unmanaged changes sit on top of managed changes, so if you have an unmanaged change to an entity, generally, you can't deploy a managed solution change to override it.  But managed changes are layered in the order in which the Solution was installed, last one in wins.
Managed solutions also allow you to uninstall, which removes the changes the Solution added.  Unmanaged solutions don't provide a way to remove the components they add. You just have to remove them manually.
The current direction Microsoft is taking, is that unmanaged solutions are for dev work, and managed are for all other environments.  They aren't quite there yet, and so I'm currently in favor of using unmanaged in most situations.

But, to answer your question, yes solutions are layered, and the order in which they are stacked (add) will effect the end result of the system.  And removing a (managed) solution, will result in the other solutions added before, to potentially be seen